# How to tell whether the colors in a video frame decoded by FFmpeg are pre-multiplied by alpha?

Tags: video, graphics, ffmpeg, compositing, premultiplied-alpha

When I decode video frames with FFmpeg (`avcodec_decode_video2()`, `sws_scale()`), with some videos (e.g., ProRes4444), I get colors pre-multiplied by alpha, and with other videos (e.g., QuickTime PNG), I get colors that aren't pre-multiplied by alpha.

How can I tell whether the colors are pre-multiplied?  Alternatively, how can I tell FFmpeg to always provide either pre-multiplied or un-pre-multiplied ("straight alpha") colors?

Comment: Good question! Ever found out the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at AVCodecContext's [color-space related properties](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#a8cd8caa7d40319324ce3d879a2edbd9f), like [AVColorSpace](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/frame_8h.html#aff71a069509a1ad3ff54d53a1c894c85).

Comment: Thanks. I checked AVCodecContext's `colorspace`, `color_range`, and `color_trc` values, but they're identical in the pre-multiplied and un-pre-multiplied movies I've tested.